# Are there several conventions (source or receiver) for the *Jones vector*? What about the one of particle physics?

Tags: optics, particle-physics, conventions, polarization

There are several conventions for defining the polarisations left and right: from the source and from the receiver. See for example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_polarization#Handedness_conventions

For the specific description with the Jones vector, are there several conventions or is there only the receiver convention?
Wikipedia seems to go in the direction that it would be receiver convention:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_calculus#Jones_vector
"Circular polarization described under Jones' convention is called : "From the point of view of the receiver."

but it is not clear.

(I have read [Simple question about Jones vector](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/320843/)
but this does not reply exactly to my question if the *Jones vector* has several conventions or only one.)

What is the convention chosen for the Jones vector in particle physics?

Comment: I imagine that would also differ from source to source... do you have a particular source in mind?

Comment: I don't have particular sources in mind

Comment: But then doesn't that make this question impossible to answer? It is impossible to know if some source I've never used uses a different convention.

Comment: The question is whether there is only one or two conventions for the *Jones* vector.

Comment: A friend of mine, who is an expert in optics and photonics, told me that there is only one convention for the Jones vector, from the point of view of the receiver.

Comment: Is your friend know that there are several conventions for defining the polarisation ? (if he is not aware of that, then it is just meaning that he uses teh convention of his thematics, which is one convention over two). Does he mean that there are several conventions for the defining the polarisation, but *only* one for the Jones vector ?